# Azure ML Python SDK Unable to get MSI token using identity secret

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I've been using the Azure ML Python SDK to create pipelines for weeks now, but all of the sudden I started getting this error when trying to get the default datastore

```
ws = Workspace.from_config()
def_blob_store = ws.get_default_datastore()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "lstm_evaluate_pipeline.py",
> line 14, in 
> def_blob_store = ws.get_default_datastore()   File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/azure_ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/core/workspace.py",
> line 1154, in get_default_datastore
> return _DatastoreClient.get_default(self)   File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/azure_ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/data/datastore_client.py",
> line 699, in get_default
> return _DatastoreClient._get_default(workspace)   File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/azure_ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/data/_exception_handler.py",
> line 19, in decorated
> raise UserErrorException(str(e)) azureml.exceptions._azureml_exception.UserErrorException:
> UserErrorException:   Message: (UserError) Unable to get MSI token
> using identity secret. The application associated with this managed
> identity  InnerException None     ErrorResponse  {
> "error": {
> "code": "UserError",
> "message": "(UserError) Unable to get MSI token using identity secret. The application associated with this managed identity"
> } }

How can I fix this? I'm running this on MacOS Monterey in a conda environment using Python 3.8. The sdk version is 1.42.0

Answer (score 0):

As noticed that the issue is with blob storage, check the following documentation, how to configure the datastore.

**Source Document:** [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-datastore?tabs=sdk-identity-based-access%2Csdk-adls-identity-access%2Csdk-azfiles-accountkey%2Ccli-adlsgen1-identity-based-access) [Link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-identity-based-data-access)